# Angular 2 update multiple variables via post request

Tags: angular, post, scope, http-post

So I have three methods in one component which all make different HTTP post request calls but in a very similar fashion.

But first, I have three class variables within my component which store the state of the response from my request all defined in a similar way. They are:

```
myPath: boolean = false;
updateVariable = [];
```

The method that does the actual post request is this:

```
onPost(obj:JSON, postPath: string): any {

  this._httpTestService.postJSON(obj, postPath).subscribe(
      data => this.updateVariable[0] = data,
      error => alert(error),
      () => console.log("update variable is: " , this.updateVariable)
  );
}
```

And my three methods are set up very similar to the one below. The reason I have this "updateVariable" is because I tried to pass in my desired variable directly but it because of the scope, it didn't update the class variable itself - just its value within the method. But even when I pass in a list, the class variable is still not getting updated when the post request returns a response. I thought it would update the class variable contained within the list but it was still '*undefined*' when accessed outside of this "onPost" method.

```
private validatePath(model: any) : boolean {
   this.obj = {"input": model.myPath}; // already defined
   this.postPath = '/v1/validate_metadata_path';
   this.updateVariable = [this.myPath]; 

   this.onPost(this.obj, this.postPath);
   return false;
}
```

So my question, is there any way I can pass in or set up my "onPost" method so that I can update any class variable I desire? OR, do I HAVE to make a separate "onPost" method for each of my three methods which need a post request?

You can assume that the HTTP post request which "onPost" makes to my HTTP service is working correctly.